# Anyway to make fields read only in modern online SharePoint forms?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I am trying to create a solution without InfoPath that requires some fields to be read only in the form itself. I have tried look ups. They are no help because they do not work with the column types. I have tried calculated fields but they cant seem to look up from another list.

The Concept:

List A, once submitted is locked. List B receives views all the information from list A and has added fields for notifications control. List C would be completely read only besides a comment field to collect approvals.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you using modern experience or classic experience? In modern experience, you can modify list forms using Power Apps & make fields read only.

Comment: Cannot use Power Apps. Not allowed in by Security.